# Is it permissible to celebrate or participate in other religion festivals?

Tags: halal-haram, practical-islam, shirk

Is it permissible to celebrate or participate in other religion festivals like Christmas (Christian), Diwali Puja (Hindu)?

**EDIT:**
Does it, in any way, impose that participating in a puja (worship) of another religion means we are supporting them in their committing [shirk](/questions/tagged/shirk)?

<sub>I've always watched my friends take part in them and felt that this is wrong to take part in other religion festivals, but I couldn't find any evidence to tell them to stop.</sub>

https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/5814/2250 is a good answer, but I did not find my answer in it.

Answer (score 2):

The typical "Christmas celebrations" is secular.  The Christian part of Christmas (going to Christ's Mass and celebrating the incarnation of the logos) would not be compatible desirable for a Muslim - IMHO.  I do not see why a moderate or liberal Muslim could not celebrate the secular traditions of Christmas such as giving gifts and even having a "Christmas tree" as they are not Christian at all (arguably pagan).  I believe it would be up to the Muslim to decide what exactly they are celebrating and then choose from there.

I believe that Quran, 2:82 would encourage Muslims to participate in the secular tradition.

**Quran, 2:82**

> { والذين آمنوا وعملوا الصالحات أولئك أصحاب الجنة هم فيها خالدون } .
>
> And those who believe and do good deeds, they are dwellers of
>   Paradise, they dwell therein forever.

Comment: I have edited my question. tried to clarify it as best as I could. please take "celebrations of other religion festivals" in a more general sense. Not limited to Christian only.

Comment: My answer will still be the same, it is what is in your heart.  It would be impossible to never do anything that, to some, would be considered religious.  For example, someone could make the argument that recycling is earth worship / pagan.  Therefore should we not recycle?  I do because I want to have less waste and be more efficient with my items - clearly not for the religious aspects.

Answer (score 0):

Islam forbid infedility. So all religion has some extent infedelism. Comparing any creation to its creation is very unacceptable by God according to islam. And God doesn't have instinct like human. Celebration of any religion festival is praising of their concept of believe which is not like following any prophet but praising a human being like God. Muslim celebrate Id and Id ul Azha it is celebration of rememberance of their prophet sacrifice so one day we will and we have to give our sacrifice and patience in faith in hard time. Ramazan is our traing period not the time of joy but we are not allowed to be grieve. Patience is strongest virtue of any religion.

I don't want to hurt. I know what liberalism mean and I am also sort of person. I am not even scholar. But if you want change the rule of game best way is to change the game. Prophet also did the same thing. He didn't change the rule of judiasm or christianity instead he built a new religion. I uses religion as a strength of being patient nothing much more else. Please do whatever pleases you. Religion is like a psychology to me.

Comment: I understand what you are saying.  Please understand that for "Christmas" there are basically two celebrations, one is secular and the other is Christian.  I agree that a Muslim would have a problem with celebrating inside a Christian church.  Many acts (knowingly or unknowingly) are practices of some religious group.  It would be difficult to stop doing any act which to another person is religious.  For example, if a religion requires that you take off your shoes before entering a house, does that mean you should never remove your shoes because you're following a different religion?

Comment: beg your pardon, but how does "infidelity" relate to this question?
I am not very good in English, so followed wikipedia for the meaning: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infidelity
states:
Infidelity (also referred to as cheating, adultery, or having an affair) is the subjective feeling that one's partner has violated a set of rules or relationship norms and this violation results in feelings of sexual jealousy and rivalry (Leeker & Carlozzi, 2012). Infidelity is a violation of a couple’s assumed or stated contract regarding emotional and/or sexual exclusivity

Comment: It is what is in your heart. If I take off my shoes, I am doing it to be respectful to my neighbor and in my heart I am not performing an act of infedility - and God knows what is in my heart. Men should not judge me or assume they know differently