# Are people who are born Christians but become atheists regarded as Christians by Muslims?

Tags: atheism

If someone was born a Christian, but decides that God doesn't exist, Jesus was an ordinary human being, and that the Holy Spirit doesn't exist, and becomes an atheist, are they still perceived as Christians by Muslims?

Someone tweeted today

> Atheists who've repeatedly insulted Christians draw a cartoon of
>   Muhammad, so Muslims burn down churches. Go figure.
>   http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-africa-30863159 …

and I wanted to know if the categories of "Christians" and "Atheists" make sense.

Related question: [In Islam, is Atheism considered a religion?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/11400/301)

Comment: Also related: http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/9407/2469

Comment: there's a big difference between believing in God and following a religion. same thing between a non-muslim faith and atheism. I wouldn't go by Zoli's argument. my personal thoughts though - i'm not an expert.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that those people are just a few- regardless of how Islam views them, not everyone is going to view ex-Christian atheists as Christians and not everyone is going to care about the distinction.

Answer (score 3):

We don't believe anyone is born a Christian, or even a Muslim, or a Jew.  We believe everyone is born upon something called a "fitra."

It's how the child is raised that becomes his way, but he/she has been given an intellect to choose what they want and are held responsible.

So if a child is raised Christian, and accepts Christianity willingly, thereafter becomes an Atheist, then he/she is considered an Atheist and not from the People of the Book.

Answer (score -4):

Even worse: They are considered as atheists!

Atheism is not a religion. Muslims consider atheists as people denying Allah, the great, and His Prophet.

This is worse than any other religion.

Comment: Do you have any references to back this up?

Comment: My answer is self explanatory.

Comment: OK. Read Quran, 8th verse, 12 paragraph.

Comment: Al-Anfal (12) That is because they opposed Allah and His messenger. Whoso opposeth Allah and His messenger, (for him) lo! Allah is severe in punishment.

Comment: @zoli, atheists don't "oppose" Allah. You can't oppose something you believe doesn't exist.

Comment: Right! One doesn't oppose a spiritual being by denying his/her existence UNLESS it is his/her message that he/she exists. Let's see what oppose those sinners who don't know about their sins. I am telling you: they unconsciously, though, oppose the spirit of the law. Do we allow at the court, as an excuse, that somebody believes that the sin he/she committed was not considered to be a sin by him/her?