# Atheism mentioned in the Quran or Hadiths?

Tags: quran, hadith, atheism

Does the Qur’an and/or hadiths address beliefs such as atheism (statements like ‘there is no god’)?

Comment: This question might answer your question: https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/11400/in-islam-is-atheism-considered-a-religion?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is being mentioned in the Al-Quran.

Surah Al-Jathiyah, verse 24. (45.24): [Reference and link here](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A2002.02.0006%3Asura%3D45%3Averse%3D24)
[image]

> **Translation**: And they say: "**There is no life other than our life in this world**. We die and we live (alternately); and nothing destroys us except the passage of time". In fact they have no knowledge of it; they are mere conjecture.

Surah al-An’am, verse 29. (6.29): [Reference and link here](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A2002.02.0006%3Asura%3D6%3Averse%3D29) 
[image]

> **Translation**: They insisted, “There is nothing beyond this worldly life and **we will never be resurrected.**

**Sources:**

> Article by Mufti Wilayah Persekutuan Malaysia. [Original version in Malay here](https://muftiwp.gov.my/artikel/bayan-linnas/696-bayan-linnas-siri-ke-107-menilai-fahaman-new-atheism). English version in [Google Translate here](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&u=https://muftiwp.gov.my/artikel/bayan-linnas/696-bayan-linnas-siri-ke-107-menilai-fahaman-new-atheism).

> Tafsir Maarif-ul-Quran. Interpretation of Surah Al-Jathiyah, verse 25. (45:24). [Click here to read](https://quran.com/45:24/tafsirs/en-tafsir-maarif-ul-quran).

Answer (score 1):

The qur'an mentions both atheism الإلحاد and the corresponding verb ألحد, يلحد (however more in the meaning of reject and refute) in several verses. Note that the modern day/use terminology is not necessarily a 100% match for the meaning of both Arabic terms.

**Atheism mentioned in the qur'an**

Some of the verses mentioning atheism are (with some comments):

- > Life is not but our worldly life - we die and live, but we will not be resurrected. ([23:37](https://legacy.quran.com/23/37))

This verse is clearly talking about atheism. People saying so reject everything, Allah, Angels, Messengers, Miracles etc., see also ([6:29](https://legacy.quran.com/6/29)), ([45:24](https://legacy.quran.com/45/24)). Their thinking is also displayed in:

> And he presents for Us an example and forgets his [own] creation. He says, "Who will give life to bones while they are ([36:78](https://legacy.quran.com/36/78))

- > And to Allah belong the best names, so invoke Him by them. And leave [the company of] those who practice deviation concerning His names. They will be recompensed for what they have been doing. ([7:180](https://legacy.quran.com/7/180))

These people are rejecting Allah's existence and therefore his names too.

- > They said, "You are not but human beings like us, and the Most Merciful has not revealed a thing. You are only telling lies." ([36:15](https://legacy.quran.com/36/15))
- > And they will say, "If only we had been listening or reasoning, we would not be among the companions of the Blaze." ([67:10](https://legacy.quran.com/67/10))

These two verse show a kind of people who reject the prophecies, messengers and miracles which also is a reference for atheism. Their behavior and thinking was explained also in:

> And if they see a miracle, they turn away and say, "Passing magic." (2)
> And they denied and followed their inclinations. But for every matter is a [time of] settlement.
> ([54:2-3](https://legacy.quran.com/54/2-3))

- > Indeed, those who inject deviation into Our verses are not concealed from Us. ...
  > ([41:40](https://legacy.quran.com/41/40))

Is regarded as an example of refusal or rejection of the qur'an and Allah's revelations and therefore as a kind of atheism.

**Atheism mentioned in the sunnah**

The sunnah also reveals covers the topic of atheism -in the modern day meaning- and some atheistic thoughts here just an example:

> Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) said, "Satan comes to one of you and says, 'Who created so-and-so? 'till he says, 'Who has created your Lord?' So, when he inspires such a question, one should seek refuge with Allah and give up such thoughts."
> (See for example in [Sahih al-Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:3276))